# SwiftUI - Change TabBar Icon Color

Tags: swift, view, colors, tabbar, swiftui

I can't change the TabBar Color in SwiftUI. I try it with the TabbedView, with the Image/Text and with a Stack. Nothing works for me.

using `.foregroundColor` doesn't work.

```
TabbedView(selection: $selection){
 TextView()
  .tag(0)
  .tabItemLabel(
 VStack {
  Image("Calendar")
   .foregroundColor(.red)
  Text("Appointments")
   .foregroundColor(.red)
  }
 ).foregroundColor(.red)
}.foregroundColor(.red)
```

Answer (score 49):

**Solution 1**

Use `renderingMode(.template)`

```swift
struct MainView: View {

    var body: some View {
       TabView {
            LoginView().tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Text("Login")
                    Image("login").renderingMode(.template)
                }
            }

            HomeView().tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Text("Home")
                    Image("home").renderingMode(.template)
                }
            }
        }.accentColor(.orange)
    }
}
```

---

**Solution 2**

Make tabItem type

```swift
enum TabViewItemType: String {
    case login  = "login"
    case home   = "home"
    case search = "search"

    var image: Image {
        switch self {
        case .login:  return Image("login")
        case .home:   return Image("home")
        case .search: return Image("search")
        }
    }

    var text: Text {
        Text(self.rawValue)
    }
}
```

```swift
struct MainView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            LoginView()
                .tabItem { TabViewItem(type: .login) }

            HomeView()
                .tabItem { TabViewItem(type: .home) }

            SearchView()
                .tabItem { TabViewItem(type: .search) }

        }.accentColor(.orange)
    }
}

struct TabViewItem: View {

    var type: TabViewItemType

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            type.image.renderingMode(.template)
            type.text

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Could even be a bit shorter: `var image: Image { return Image(self.rawValue)  }`

Comment: We could further improve by setting all of the assets for tab item to use the `template` rendingMode from the asset catalogue just to tidy things up a bit more.

Comment: THANK YOU. .accentColor was the elusive modifier. All other resources claimed .foregroundColor, and it wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 27):

Use `accentColor`:

```swift
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            NavigationView {
                HomeView()
            }.navigationBarTitle("Home")
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        if selection == 0 {
                            Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "house")
                        }
                        Text("Home")
                    }
                }
            .tag(0)
            NavigationView {
                SettingsView()
            }.navigationBarTitle("Settings")
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                        Text("Settings")
                    }
                }
                .tag(1)
        }.accentColor(.purple)
```

Comment: It's work but this mean entire app now accentColor is purple

Comment: @tuandapen just use .accentColor(.none) on the views (HomeView, SettingsView) and it won't propagate

Answer (score 13):

You can use **UITabBar.appearance()** to do some customisation until Apple comes with a more standard way of updating SwiftUI **TabView**

**Change TabItem (text + icon) color**

```
init() {
  UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
}
```

**Change TabView background color**

```
init() {
  UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
}
```

Overall code looks like this -

```
struct ContentView: View {

   init() {
       // UITabBar customization
   }

  var body: some View {
     TabView(selection: $selection) {
         FirstTabView()
              .tabItem {
                  VStack {
                     Image(systemName: "map")
                     Text("Near Me")
                  }
              }
     }
  }

}
```

Use **.accentColor** modifier for changing color of **selected** tabItem

After trying many options this worked for me..

Answer (score 9):

I think you can just use the accentColor of TabView，it works for me :]

```
TabView {
...
}.accentColor(Color.red)
```

Answer (score 6):

On iOS16 .accentColor(Color) is deprecated.
You can use .tint(Color) on the TabView instead.

```
 TabView {
        Text("First Tab")
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                Text("First")
            }
 }.tint(Color.yellow)
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to change the not-selected color?  Is there a proper (not going back to UIKit appearance for example) way in iOS 16 for this?

Comment: The answer mentioning UITabBar.appearance() works for non-selected items. It looks a little "hacky" however, a lot of SwiftUI still is hacky. Might be the easiest solution compared to building any UIKit wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

I made an extension for Image which initialises with a UIImage with a tint color:

```
extension Image {
    init(_ named: String, tintColor: UIColor) {
        let uiImage = UIImage(named: named) ?? UIImage()
        let tintedImage = uiImage.withTintColor(tintColor,
                                                renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate)
        self = Image(uiImage: tintedImage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently `SwiftUI` does not have a direct method for that.

We've to use the `UIKit` method for that unless `SwiftUI` introduces any new solution.

try below code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    }

    var body: some View {
        return TabbedView {
            Text("This is tab 1")
                .tag(0)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("tab1")
            }
            Text("This is tab 2")
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("tab1")
            }
            Text("This is tab 3")
                .tag(2)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("tab1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to set up accent color for entire app with SwiftUI interface, you just need to define AccentColor in Assets.xcassets file like in the picture below. TabBar icons will get it without any additional code.

[image]